# why this is true in cyclic code?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, coding-theory

In the book "Fundamentals of Error-Correcting Codes" this was written

If $t =$ ord$_n(q)$, then $F_{q^t}$ contains a primitive nth root of unity $\alpha$, but no smaller extension field of $F_q$ contains such a primitive root.
(As $\alpha^i$ are distinct for $0 < i < n$ and $(\alpha^i)^n = 1$); $F_{q^t}$ contains all the roots of $x^n-1$. So $F_{q^t}$
is called a splitting field of $x^n-1$ over $F_q$.

could any one help me

How this (As $\alpha^i$ are distinct for $0 \le i < n$ and $(\alpha^i)^n = 1$) ?

[the book](https://books.google.ps/books?id=RAsjychHkLYC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=find%20the%20generating%20idempotent%20e(x)%20for%20a%20cyclic%20code%20C%20from%20the%20generator%20polynomial%20g(x)&source=bl&ots=GwEyUvwe1k&sig=-MeQmX18w8STPF9zN0vWFEPDp-I&hl=ar&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=find%20the%20generating%20idempotent%20e(x)%20for%20a%20cyclic%20code%20C%20from%20the%20generator%20polynomial%20g(x)&f=false) page 122
\

update :$\alpha^i$ not $\alpha_i$

Comment: It is simple to see using the basic properties of cyclic groups. But you need the piece of information that the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_{q^m}$ is cyclic of order $q^m-1$. Has that been explained to you already?

Comment: see the update please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple to see using the basic properties of cyclic groups. But you need the piece of information that the multiplicative group of $F_q^m$ is cyclic of order $q^m−1$.